# In ASP.NET MVC 5, what method set the User object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

I have a application that uses multiple controller inheritance. I override the `Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)` in multiple levels of my inheritance , but each time I override the `Initialize` method, I call `base.Initialize(requestContext);`

```
[Authorize]
public class FirstBaseController: Controller
{
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        // Set few custom global things
    }

}

public class SecondBaseController: FirstBaseController
{

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        // At this point, I am expecting that the `User` object is already set by identity
        //check the claims value here.
    }
}
```

However if I try to access the `User` object from inside the `Initialize` method I found it not yet set!

At what point in time does the framework sets the `User` object? Which method before the action method I can override where the `User` object will be set already?

I don't want to use action filter here because I want this logic to get executed on every request.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why do you think Action filters aren't executed on every request?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I don't want to manually have to add attribute over every method   unless there is a way to add it to all the methods. + is it even possible to access the `User` object from within an action filter?

Comment: You can access the User object via `HttpContext.Current.User` from an action filter.  If you look at the actual MVC source code, you'll see that the User property on the controller simply returns the User from the current http context.

Comment: Also, regarding action filters - you can apply them to a controller and they will be applied to all methods in that controller (or a base class controller, and they will be applied to all methods on all controllers derived from that base class)

Comment: There is a way to add it to all methods.  You use a global filter.  See https://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to vary somewhat depending on what method you are using for authentication, but you should be safe to access the `User` in the `OnActionExecuting' method.

You could also implement that as an action filter and apply that filter to each controller (or to just a base-class controller - it will "carry through" to any controllers that inherit from it)

Answer (score 1):

Using JustDecompile to see the references, the User property really navigates up to the `RequestContext` reference passed into Initialize (which has a reference to `HttpContext`).  So in Initialize, if the `requestContext` variable passed into the method has a property `HttpContext` that is null or `HttpContext.User` reference is null, then the current user is not available in `Initialize()`.

OnActionExecuting is a good place like @Eric said.